# Display post taxonomies tree

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms, get-children

I was able to get all the items of a custom taxonomy for a post, like this:

```
$args=array('orderby'=>'parent',"fields" => "all");
$term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'tvr_amenity', $args);
```

My problem is that i would like to show the tree (respecting the parents)

So i would like to get them ordered by name and parent but i cant find anything related on codex..

any idea how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about:

```
$taxName = "tvr_amenity";
$terms = get_terms($taxName,array('parent' => 0));
foreach($terms as $term) {
   echo '<a href="'.get_term_link($term->slug,$taxName).'">'.$term->name.'</a>';
   $term_children = get_term_children($term->term_id,$taxName);
   echo '<ul>';
   foreach($term_children as $term_child_id) {
       $term_child = get_term_by('id',$term_child_id,$taxName);
       echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term_child->name, $taxName ) . '">' . $term_child->name . '</a></li>';
   }
   echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for! I love you mate!

Comment: How we can show all subchildren like this?

Comment: @Alexandros All subchildren of what?

Answer (score 1):

With recursion for all deep.

```
function tree() {

    $taxName = "custom_tax_name";
    $terms = get_terms($taxName, array('parent' => 0, 'fields' => 'ids'));
    subtree($terms, 0, $taxName);
}

function subtree($children_ids, $parrent_id, $taxName) {

    if ( !empty($children_ids) ){
        echo '<ul>';
            foreach($children_ids as $term_child_id) {
                $term_child = get_term_by('id', $term_child_id, $taxName);
                if ( $term_child->parent == $parrent_id) {
                    echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term_child->term_id, $taxName ) . '">' . $term_child->name . '</a>';
                    $term_children = get_term_children($term_child_id, $taxName);
                    subtree($term_children, $term_child_id, $taxName);
                    echo '</li>';
                }
            }
        echo '</ul>';
    }

}
```